# Need str.split Function to get a pair format

Tags: pine-script

I have a list of pairs as following and need a function to get "UST_pair" format, such as USDT_1INCH , USDT_AAVE, USDT_ACA  etc.  anybody help?

```
s01 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:1INCHUSDT  ' )
s02 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:AAVEUSDT  ' )
s03 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ACAUSDT  ' )
s04 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ACHUSDT  ' )
s05 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ACMUSDT  ' )
s06 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ADAUSDT  ' )
s07 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ADXUSDT  ' )
s08 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:AGLDUSDT  ' )
s09 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:AIONUSDT  ' )
s10 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:AKROUSDT  ' )
s11 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALCXUSDT  ' )
s12 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALGOUSDT  ' )
s13 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALICEUSDT  ' )
s14 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALPACAUSDT  ' )
s15 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALPHAUSDT  ' )
s16 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ALPINEUSDT  ' )
s17 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:AMPUSDT  ' )
s18 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ANCUSDT  ' )
s19 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ANKRUSDT  ' )
s20 = input.symbol(' BINANCE:ANTUSDT  ' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    f_strRightOf(_str, _of) =>
    // string _str: string to separate.
    // string _op : separator character.
    string[] _chars = str.split(_str, "")
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    int _ofPos = array.indexof(_chars, _of)
    string[] _substr = array.new_string(0)
    if _ofPos >= 0 and _ofPos < _len - 1
        _substr := array.slice(_chars, _ofPos + 1, _len)
    string _return = array.join(_substr, "")


// ————— Function returning the rightmost `_n` characters in `_str`.
f_strRight(_str, _n) =>
    // string _str: source string.
    // int    _n  : number of rightmost characters to return.
    string[] _chars = str.split(_str, "")
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    int _beg = math.max(0, _len - _n)
    string[] _substr = array.new_string(0)
    if _beg < _len
        _substr := array.slice(_chars, _beg, _len)
    string _return = array.join(_substr, "")


// ————— Function that replaces a character at position `_pos` in the `_src` string with the `_str` character or string.
f_strReplace(_src)=>    // Thx to @LonesomeTheBlue.
    // string _src  : source string.
    // int    _pos  : position of character to be replaced. The first character's position is 0.
    // string _str  : replacement character or string.
    string[] _chars = str.split(_src, "")
    string[] _str =array.new_string()
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    for i=0 to _len-5
        array.insert(_str, i, array.get(_chars,i))
        
    string _return = array.join(_str, "")



coin(symbol) =>
    string ss= f_strRightOf(symbol, ":")
    string coin= f_strRight(ss, 4) +'_'+str.tostring(f_strReplace(ss))
    coin
```